# Soql query to retrieve opportunities between two dates

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to retrieve opportunities created between 01-01-2011 and 06-30-2011.

```
Select o.CreatedDate, o.Id, o.LastModifiedDate
from Opportunity o 
where   o.CreatedDate > '1/1/2011' and o.CreatedDate <  '12/31/2011'
order by  o.LastModifiedDate
```

since createdate is a datetime i get a error saying createdDate is datetime and should not be enclosed in quotes.

Can someone help on how to get this query working. I just want this query to get it running in apex explorer, this is not part of apex code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SOQL query to retrieve opportunities between two dates:

```
Select o.CreatedDate, o.Id, o.LastModifiedDate 
from Opportunity o 
where   o.CreatedDate > 2011-01-01T00:00:00Z and o.CreatedDate < 2011-12-31T00:00:00Z
```